# fseek(binaryFile, 0, 1) stops a while loop from being an infinite loop

Tags: c, file, while-loop, fseek

The code from below takes from a file data about students and add a point to the first subject's grade for a specified group. However in the while loop that does that, fseek(binaryFile, 0, 1) prevents the loop from being an infinite loop. I found out that fseek(binaryFile, 0, 1) is used to go from writing to reading mode but I can't understand how it works and how it prevents an infinite loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int identificationNumber;
    char name[30];
    int year;
    int group;
    int numberOfGrades;
    int grades[15];
} Student;

void main()
{
    FILE *binaryFile;
    Student student;

    char fileName[20];
    printf("Enter the binary file name (.dat): ");
    gets(fileName);

    binaryFile = fopen(fileName, "rb+");

    if (!binaryFile)
    {
        printf("The file could not be opened");
    }
    else
    {
        int groupNumberWanted;
        printf("Enter the group number: ");
        scanf("%d", &groupNumberWanted);

        while (!feof(stdin))
        {
            rewind(binaryFile);
            fread(&student, sizeof(Student), 1, binaryFile);
            int doesGroupExist = 0;

            while (!feof(binaryFile))
            {
                if (groupNumberWanted == student.group)
                {
                    doesGroupExist = 1;
                    if (student.grades[0] < 10)
                    {
                        student.grades[0] = student.grades[0] + 1;
                    }
                    fseek(binaryFile, ftell(binaryFile) - sizeof(Student), 0);
                    fwrite(&student, sizeof(Student), 1, binaryFile);
                    fseek(binaryFile, 0, 1); // without this line, the while loop is an infinite loop
                }
                fread(&student, sizeof(Student), 1, binaryFile);
            }

            if (doesGroupExist == 0)
            {
                printf("The group wasn't found.\n");
            }

            printf("Enter the group number: ");
            scanf("%d", &groupNumberWanted);
        }
        fclose(binaryFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: `feof` is not for checking whether the file's end has been reached. The return values of the read/write functions do that by returning `NULL` strings, `EOF` or by indicating that zero bytes were read.

Comment: Please use the constants `SEEK_SET|CUR|END` for clarity, whose numerical values many of us won't have memorized. (I haven't.)

Comment: Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Please see a [man page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=msvc-160) for more info which says *"When you switch from writing to reading, you must use an intervening call to either fflush or to a file positioning function."* Presumably the supposed 'infinite loop' is the result of not doing so.

Comment: As to your question: if the `"r+"` and `"w+"` modes want you to do a positioning when changing modes, that's the thing to do. If you don't do it and then don't get the correct results on reading, it's your fault. There isn't anything to understand, it's just the way things are implemented under the hood. (In general, I see the `"+"` modes used very often by beginners who implement a database, wild `fseek` jumping and all. I think it's much better to have two load/save functions for the database and do all manipulation in memory.)

Answer (score 2):

The `C` Standard requires an intervening call to the `fflush` function or to a file positioning function (`fseek`, `fsetpos`, or `rewind`) between an input and output operation, and a file positioning function between an output and input operation.

The relevant section in the Standard is

> When a file is opened with update mode ('+' as the second or third
> character in the above list of mode argument values), both input and
> output may be performed on the associated stream. However, output
> shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to
> the fflush function or to a file positioning function (fseek, fsetpos,
> or rewind), and input shall not be directly followed by output without
> an intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input
> operation encounters end- of-file. Opening (or creating) a text file
> with update mode may instead open (or create) a binary stream in some
> implementations.

from [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3p7](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3p7)

---

Couple of aside notes about the code:

- `void main() { /* ... */ }` is not a correct way to define the `main` function.
- `gets` no longer exists in the C language. Even if it existed, `fgets` (or another function which sets a limit on the number of characters read) must have been used instead.
- `while (!feof(fp)) { /* ... */ }` is not a correct looping construct to iterate over the records in a stream.